# XAML: How to set button in a template equal to a button in the class the template is for?

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to use buttons in code since they affect each other.

I can use

```
public class ObservableButtons : ObservableCollection<Button> { }
```

but for just one button this seems a bit overkill.
Is there an easier solution for this?

Using a Trigger seems to be the smarter option atm, I'm just curious.

Comment: What kind of interaction between buttons do you want to implement?

Comment: Clicking on the XAML-button should click on the class button and the visibility should be linked. So I'd like them to be the same. But those two things would suffice.

Comment: You could use MVVM pattern to bind their Visibility property to a single property of view model

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll do that. Thank you.